# Not able to find "File Preview" lightning custom component introduced in winter 18 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-community

As per the winter 18 release , there is document related to create a custom preview component.
Adding screenshot.
Let me know where to find that component.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you missed the big disclaimer above the  Release Notes:

> Note: This release is in preview. Features described here don’t become
>   generally available until the latest general availability date that
>   Salesforce announces for this release. Before then, and where features
>   are noted as beta, pilot, or developer preview, we can’t guarantee
>   general availability within any particular time frame or at all. Make
>   your purchase decisions only on the basis of generally available
>   products and features.

That being said, it is normal that the component is not available yet.

Comment: is this functionality is available now,
can any give some insight for creating this one